# Showing subgroup of $(\mathbb{Q},+)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $\displaystyle H=\{\frac{m}{7^k}:m\in\mathbb{Z},k\in\mathbb{N}_0\} \subseteq \mathbb{Q}$

Show that $H$ is a subgroup of $(\mathbb{Q},+)$

Is it enough to show that $g,h\in H \Rightarrow g+(-h)\in H$?

If it is enough, then $g=\frac{m}{7^k}$, $h=\frac{n}{7^l}$

and $g+(-h)=\frac{m}{7^k}-\frac{n}{7^l}=\frac{m7^l-n7^k}{7^{k+l}} \in H$

Is the last equality true?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are right. To summarise: when you add fractions the denominator for the sum will be the lcm of the original denominators; lcm of two powers of the same number is simply the biggr one; of course cancellation may take place then you get a factor of the lcm which is fine.

Comment: Yes, your proof is correct.

Comment: Actually what you have done can be used, along with the fact that there are infinitely many prime numbers,  to prove that the rational numbers under addition is  not a finitely generated group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You must also show that $H$ is non-empty, but this is rather obvious.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because $m7^{l}-n 7^k\in \mathbb{Z}$, then you can to define $m'=m7^{l}-n 7^k\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 0):

Write
$$
H = \mathbb Z \cup \dfrac{1}{7} \mathbb Z \cup \dfrac{1}{7^2} \mathbb Z \cup \cdots = \bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{7^n} \mathbb Z
$$

Each $\dfrac{1}{7^n} \mathbb Z$ is an additive subgroup of $\mathbb Q$ and so is $H$, being a union of a chain of subgroups (every group operation you need to do on elements of $H$ occurs in one of those subgroups and so can be done within $H$).